# Calling a user e-mail to add to a mailto link PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mailto, author

So I'm currently working on calling an author's e-mail address into php, then using a mailto: image link so that users can easily e-mail them.

At the moment I am able to call the author's e-mail address and display the image. However, I am unable to add the link to the mailto command, it just echos above the image.

Below I have my current code (which has been censored), so any help would be awesome.

```
    <?php
    $email =  ((the_author_meta( 'email' )));
    $src = '[Censored Link]'; // image url
    echo ('<a href=mailto:'. $email .'><img style="border:none;" src="'. $src .'" /></a>');
    ?>
```

Comment: How about some doublequotes around your `href`?

Comment: Missing quotations on the href-property <a href="mailto:' . $email . '">.

Comment: You need to check out the difference between `the_author_meta()` and `get_the_author_meta()`.

Answer (score 3):

As the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) says:

> Use `get_the_author_meta()` if you need to return (not display) the information.

You're currently using:

```
$email =  ((the_author_meta( 'email' )));
```

Change it to:

```
$email =  get_the_author_meta('email'); //no need of the brackets here
```

Also, I'd rewrite the echo statement as follows:

```
echo "<a href='mailto: $email'>
<img style='border:none;' src='$src'/>
</a>";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can probably get rid of the brackets around the function call, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has been annoying me for days!